EdgeDB stopped working after installing Docker Desktop - Windows 11

I installed WSL on Windows 11.
I got it working by following the advice here: Firewall blocking WSL 2

In particular, this resolved the issue
I was able to fully resolve this issue of Norton 360 blocking egress SSH traffic from WSL to remote hosts. This was resolved on Windows 11 and Norton360 V22.23.5.106. This should also work as specified on Windows 10. After installing Norton, open "Norton Anti-Virus", open "Device Security". A new window opens. At the top menu bar, select "Settings". Then select "Firewall". Under "Program Control" add bash.exe and wsl.exe as directed in this solution above by zwxi. Then, select "Traffic Rules". Add a traffic rule with the following : Action: Allow, Connections: Connect to any computer, Computers: Any computer, Communications: TCP, add remote port 22 (weird UI, select individually specified ports, then enter 22), Advanced: Apply rule for NAT traversal traffic Off.

Installed EdgeDB and got familiar with it.  Set up some sample databases, inserted data and so forth - so far so good.

Next I installed Docker Desktop

System restarted.

When I next tried to use the EdgeDB CLI it is failing to connect to the database with the following error


C:\projects\try>edgedb
Connecting to EdgeDB instance 'try' at localhost:10702...edgedb error: Connection error: ClientConnectionFailedError: cannot establish connection for 30s
Same problem with another instance
C:\projects\easydb>edgedb
Connecting to EdgeDB instance 'easydb' at localhost:10703...edgedb error: Connection error: ClientConnectionFailedError: cannot establish connection for 30s

Tried adding Firewall rules for port 10702 and 10703, but this did not work.
What could Docker have changed during installation - network/firewall/other rules?
How to go about debugging this?
Pretty convinced it is Docker installation that did it, because no other change was made between EdgeDB working and its stopping to work.

Thanks for any help.

I uninstalled Docker Desktop and rebooted and EdgeDB has started working again.  However, I eventually want to use Docker, so I still need help debugging the issue. Thanks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

No code is involved at this stage.  This is just basic execution from the command line to connect to EdgeDB instance, it fails to connect after Docker Desktop was installed, and has resumed working after removing Docker.
With Docker installed:
C:\projects\try>edgedb Connecting to EdgeDB instance 'try' at localhost:10702...edgedb error: Connection error: ClientConnectionFailedError: cannot establish connection for 30s
Without Docker Desktop (before and after removal):
(base) C:\projects\try>edgedb
EdgeDB 5.6+51fd5fe (repl 5.2.3+92d41c6)
Type \help for help, \quit to quit.
try:main>
